# Multitail over ssh

Tags: ssh, multitail

I want to use [`multitail`](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) over ssh. But following command fails:

```
$ multitail "ssh dev-04 tail -f /opt/app/app.log"
Error opening file ssh docdev-04 tail -f /opt/alfresco/share.log (No such file or directory)
```

However just `ssh` with `tail` works fine and displays the content of the file:

```
$ ssh dev-04 tail -f /opt/app/app.log            
Enter passphrase for key '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa': 
2016-08-03 09:40:27,926 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered 8 Package Description Documents (+0 failed)
```

I would guess that the problem is in the password request. But anyway I don't know how to make it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the manpage of multitail you need the -l flag:

`-l command
Command to execute in a window. Parameter is the command. Do not forget to use "'s if the external command needs parameter! (e.g. -l "ping host").`

So, in your case, try:
`multitail -l "ssh dev-04 tail -f /opt/app/app.log"`

In your current form, multitail expects the argument `"ssh dev-04 tail -f /opt/app/app.log"` to be a file, not an application to execute and capture.

I don't know how well the password input would work, but if that also fails, try ssh authentication by keys. (see, for instance: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys)

Comment: Or more particularly the section on [ssh-agent](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#SSH_agents) since the OP's screen copy-paste indicates he is already using SSH keys, just without `ssh-agent`.

Comment: My bad - should read documentation, I thought `-l` is used if there is more that one window. Actually with `-l` and ssh-agent it works perfectly! Thanks @madeddie and @user4556274!

Comment: How could I run sudo before tailing the file?

Comment: Do you mean run tail with sudo? Using the example above it would simply be `multitail -l "ssh dev-04 sudo tail -f /opt/app/app.log"`. Mind you this would need sudo privileges with NOPASSWD