# multitail over ssh AND sudo

Tags: ssh, sudo, multitail

This question: [Multitail over ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302559/multitail-over-ssh)
helped me to multitail from a remote location.

But my problem is one step deeper:

I need to run "sudo su" before I can tail the files.

How can I change user to su before I tail the file with

```
multitail -l "ssh dev-04 tail -f /opt/app/app.log"
```

Comment: Yup - there's always an asshole who will downgrade a question without a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `sudo su`  is redundant , You  must be able to do `sudo tail`

Advice , before run a complex complex , try always the simple version

so:

```
ssh dev-04 sudo tail -f /opt/app/app.log
```

if this is work you can run :

```
multitail -l "ssh dev-04 sudo tail -f /opt/app/app.log"
```

Comment: Beautiful! Just one small correction - I needed a tty to run sudo, so the final command was multitail -l "ssh -t dev-04 sudo tail -f /opt/app/app.log"
Thanks for the help!